# Swift ios-charts Set Bar Color on Highlight

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, ios-charts

Within the ios-charts delegate method:

```
@objc func chartValueSelected(chartView: ChartViewBase, entry: ChartDataEntry, dataSetIndex: Int, highlight: ChartHighlight) { }
```

I would like to **change the color of the bar that was selected**. Is this possible?

Comment: Can't you just set the `highlightColor` on the set?

Comment: Ah, on the set. You're right, sorry for the silly question, I don't know much of the ios-charts framework yet. Feel free to post as an answer if you want

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change the color for highlights using:

```
highlightColor
```

on the chart data set.

The problem with ios-charts is that they don't have a good documentation and they link only to the Android documentation and some of the variables/methods are not very programmer friendly because they were translated from the Android version and don't really follow Swift naming conventions.

If you are looking for something, just open the source code for the given chart or its renderer.

Comment: some color is getting mixed into the color. As I am setting it as yellow and it is giving me parrot-green color

Comment: @sulthan as you can see I am setting higlightedColor but its not showing on tap of touch bar    var set1: BarChartDataSet! = nil
        set1 = BarChartDataSet(entries: yVals, label: title)
        set1.drawValuesEnabled = false
        set1.highlightColor = AppColors.themeBlue.withAlphaComponent(1.0)
        set1.highlightAlpha = 1.0

Answer (score 1):

You can change `highlightColor` and `highlightAlpha` on the chart data set.

Comment: I tried by setting these two values, still no color change on bar selection.